# Aplicar setItemOnClickListener no GridView de Botões. Kotlin ou Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Eu fiz um gridView de botões, porém quando eu utilizo o método setOnItemClickListener para acionar os respectivos botões, ele não funciona.

Quero utilizar os botões para que eu possa acionar uma intent, sabendo que só se pode acionar uma intent dentro de uma activity. Eu consigo fazer o botão funcionar dentro do Adapter da Grid, porém fora não.

Comment: Por favor cole o código para conseguirmos te ajudar

Answer (score 1):

> sabendo que só se pode acionar uma intent dentro de uma activity.

Isso não é verdade. É possível em qualquer lado, desde que tenha um Context disponível.

Se quer implementar, no Adapter, o OnClickListener de cada botão, apenas necessita de passar um Context no construtor e usá-lo para criar o Intent.

Caso deseje usar OnItemClickListener veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/247453/2541). Nela é explicado porque ele não funciona nesse tipo de caso e como fazer para funcionar.